# How to stop elements resizing when I resize my browser

Tags: html, css, resize

I am using this website as an example. https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLtFd.jpg Here I have a screenshot of the website in fullscreen. However when I resize the page https://i.stack.imgur.com/15sBq.jpg you can see that the page almost cuts off elements instead of jumbling them all around. Is there a way I can achive this cutting off affect in html and css only? If you need my code just ask in the comments.

Comment: you have to set divs in percentage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to create a fixed width, you can create a wrapper div and set its width to 800px (just as an example) and it's margin to 0 and auto to Center the div if you would like.

If you'd like to make it responsive you can change width to max-width.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.wrapper {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
} 
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <p>Content here!</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You probably didn't need to come here for that question haha. All you need to do is set a width on the body or a div.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you so much! This answer was a lot better than the other one. This helped loads man.

Comment: Glad I could help, by the way there is nothing wrong with asking questions, just try to do a little more research first my friend!

Comment: Alright. Thanks for your time. Your answer honestly helped me loads. Thank you.